# How to get the fonts being used in a UILabel and the ranges they span for PDF generation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, fonts, pdf-generation

I'm currently developing an iOS app that at a very high level allows a user to enter text into a text box that will get sent to a server for incorporation into a dynamically generated PDF. The server uses Node.js & PDFKit.

We are localising the app for pretty much every language supported by iOS. The text the user enters is UTF-8 encoded when sent to the server. The problem I face is knowing which font (or fonts) to use server side to ensure the characters show up correctly in the server side generated PDF.

In the iOS client app there is a single UILabel showing a preview of the text a user has entered into a UITextField. The UILabel showing the preview has a single custom font applied that only has support for Greek & Latin characters. Interestingly when a mixture of characters are entered from different alphabets (possible if the user has multiple keyboards) latin, cyrillic, etc. they display correctly in the UILabel despite the fact the custom font does not support them:

[image: A single UILabel showing text in various languages]

I guess there is some kind of "font fallback" going on, however as the client app is being localised to support many languages this behaviour is desirable.

My question is how can I know server side which fonts are being used, and the range of characters they cover in the preview UILabel? Somehow I need to replicate this behaviour server side so that the text in the generated PDF approximately matches the client preview.

Alternatively is it possible to determine server side what fonts I should use for a given character?

Comment: You would need to check with PDFkit to check on fonts. Typically one can use multiple fonts and use character by character selection in some applications but you will need to have fonts around to embed in PDF. Or fallback to something like Arial Unicode